# TikZ: Parametric Gnuplot plot fails to appear

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to create a parametric curve using the source code below. It will not show up on my graph at all. The curve is supposed to look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{textbox}=[draw=white, fill=white, thick, rectangle]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, domain=-4:4]
   \draw [<->,thick] (-4,0)--coordinate(x axis)(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
   \draw [<->, thick] (0,-4)--coordinate(y axis)(0,4) node[above] {$y$};
   \foreach \x/\xtext in {-3.5/-3.5, -1.5/-1.5, 1.5/1.5, 3.5/3.5}
   \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt)--(0pt,-2pt);
   \node [below] at (-3.5,-0.) {$-2\pi$};
   \node [below] at (-1.5,-0.) {$-\pi$};
   \node [below] at (1.5,-0.) {$\pi$};
   \node [below] at (3.5,-0.) {$2\pi$};
   \foreach\y/\ytext in {-3.5/-3.5, -1.5/-1.5, 1.5/1.5, 3.5/3.5}
   \draw [shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt)--(-2pt,0pt);
   \node [left] at (-0.,3.5) {$2\pi$};
   \node [left] at (-0.,1.5) {$\pi$};
   \node [right] at (0.,-1.5) {$-\pi$};
   \node [right] at (0.,-3.5) {$-2\pi$}; 
   \draw [color=red] plot[id=cos] function{y=t+2cos5t};
   \draw [color=blue] plot[id=sin] function{x=t+2sint};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Downvoter: Why the down-vote? Please explain to the OP, what issue you are seeing in this post!

Comment: @BMarc20 Your picture shows `x=t+2sin(2t)` but your code snippet has `x=t+2sin(t)`: which do you want?

Comment: @JosephWright I forgot the 2 in the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few things wrong here. You've not told TikZ that the plot is parametric, you've not put both the *x* and *y* components into a single `\draw` line and you've not given the formulae in the correct form. You can tell something is up as Gnuplot warns

```
"test.cos.gnuplot", line 2: undefined variable: t
"test.sin.gnuplot", line 2: undefined variable: t
```

in the log. Changing the input to

```
\draw [samples=1000] plot[parametric] function{t+2*sin(2*t),t+2*cos(5*t)};
```

gives me a plot :it's a one-line change so I've not included everything else. To get your plot, i'd also up the domain to say `-7:7`.

Personally, I'd use `pgfplots`, which uses the same underlying ideas but is I find easier to read. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      axis lines  = center                                ,
      xtick       = {-6.28318,-3.14159,...,6.3}           ,
      xticklabels = {$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $0$, $\pi$, $2\pi$} ,
      ytick       = {-6.28318,-3.14159,...,6.3}           ,
      yticklabels = {$-2\pi$, $-\pi$, $0$, $\pi$, $2\pi$}
    ]
    \addplot[domain = -7:7, parametric, samples = 1000]
      gnuplot {t+2*sin(2*t),t+2*cos(5*t)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: There's something wrong with the evaluation of the function. For instance, if t=-6.22, x=-5.97 and that's right. But if t=-4, x=-5.98 and we see that the graph of the function is wrong because your curve is simple near x=-6 while the original one is not (see the picture in the question).

Comment: @Luigi Evaluation is down to Gnuplot not `pgf`. I'd purse that first using Gnuplot or some other system for doing calculations before I did typeset-quality plots.

Comment: Found the error: x=t+2sin(2t) and not x=t+2sin(t)

Comment: @Luigi Yes, I notice that too: the usual rule is to start from the OPs code. I guess a comment on the question is the best plan here.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I started from the picture...

Comment: @Luigi My professor had explained to me that I should've been able to make it just putting it in the way I had it. He never mentioned the use of that package to us.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Want to go with `pgfplots`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad,variable=t,axis lines=middle]
\addplot[red,domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=200]
({t+2*sin(t)},
{t+2*cos(5*t)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was editing in my `pgfplots` version when your answer appeared, honest!

Comment: @JosephWright Oh Sorry, After upvoting your answer, I thought I will give a quick `pgfplots` try! :)

Comment: There's something wrong with the evaluation of the function. For instance, if t=-6.22, x=-5.97 and that's right. But if t=-4, x=-5.98 and we see that the graph of the function is wrong because your curve is simple near x=-6 while the original one is not (see the picture in the question).

Comment: Found the error: x=t+2sin(2t) and not x=t+2sin(t)

Comment: As Joseph stated, the "original sin" (in the true sense of the word) is in the OPs code. I looked to the picture and didn't realize that the error was in the question.